# Access XML file using PHP

Tags: php, xml

I have a xml file which has an entry

```
<content type="html"></content>
```

Can I access it as `echo $result->content;`

If not let me know , coz the above does not seem to be working, there are pics, which I want to display.

Thanks
Jean

Answer (score 2):

```
$result = simplexml_load_file("/path/to/file.xml");
```

should do what you want.

EDIT:
You've said that you have the content as HTML. If it's stored as HTML when it's passed to `echo` it's displayed as HTML content.

However, to get HTML *into* the XML document in the first place, it needs to be stored either as character entities or as a CDATA section.

If it's character entities, then all you need to do is call:

```
$result->content = html_entities_decode($result->content);
```

If you've stored it as CDATA, then you need to [change the call](http://maisonbisson.com/blog/post/11257/php5s-simplexml-now-passes-cdata-content/) to simplexml_load_file to the following:

```
$result = simplexml_load_file("/path/to/file.xml", "SimpleXMLElement", LIBXML_NO_CDATA);
```

Comment: You would have noticed the echo, what I need it is to display it as an html content

Comment: @Jean: But you already have this code: `echo $result->content`. Macha only told what `$result` should be. Or don't I get your point?

Comment: I can very well parse the xml file, my issue is I want it as html--

<content type="html"></content>

Comment: If it's HTML going in, it's HTML going out... _but_, to store HTML in an XML file, you need to put the HTML as a CDATA section, or replace the angle brackets with character entities.